# Public reprojection services

Tags: coordinate-system, point

Are there any free public services where I can send one point in a coordsystem and it returns the point reprojected in a specified coordinate system?

I will not be doing many requests, for now it is just for a demo.

Comment: This would certainly be a cool new feature to add to spatialreference.org...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like MassGIS has one:  http://lyceum.massgis.state.ma.us/wiki/doku.php?id=point_reprojection  Looks like it is only in the ESRI, non-open flavor though.

Answer (score 8):

use [proj4](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/)
cs2cs can reproject a point or even a file of points

Comment: cool! I actually tried proj4js and it seems to work fine except for some little bugs ;-)

Answer (score 8):

This already exists on spatialreference.org, but it is not widely publicized.  Pass in some GeoJSON of your point and out will come a reprojected point.  This is used to drive the map in the existing interface.

> http://spatialreference.org/projection/?json=%7B%22type%22%3A%22Feature%22%2C%20%22geometry%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22Point%22%2C%20%22coordinates%22%3A%5B-93.0%2C%2042.00%5D%7D%2C%22properties%22%3A%7B%7D%7D&inref=EPSG:4326&outref=EPSG:26915&callback=project_out

If something starts pounding the heck out of it, expect that we'll turn it off.  You have been warned :)

Comment: Nice! And no worries, it only for a demo I wont over hit it :-)

Answer (score 5):

GIS Lounge has online and offline converters listed here:

http://gislounge.com/projections-and-coordinate-systems/

Answer (score 4):

I realise that this question is a little old now, however we have a great new site that allows you to do just what you ask.

http://georepository.com/home.html

More details about the Geodetic Calculator can be found at:
http://georepository.com/geodetic_calculator.html

Answer (score 2):

I found [nearby.org.uk](http://nearby.org.uk/api/convert-help.php) but you need to register and it only supports a few coordinate systems and postal code queries.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Online CS2CS](http://cs2cs.mygeodata.eu) - it uses proj4 and allows you to select all known coordinate system and change parameters or define your own coordinate system.